# How to override color scheme in neovim lua config file?

Tags: lua, lua-table, vim-plugin, neovim

how can I override some color scheme value in neovim lua config file? I am trying to use .lua instead of .vim. Previously in my init.vim file I have this to override some settings I want to enable these settings for init.lua file also. How I can achieve this?

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=0 guibg=lightgrey
highlight Normal ctermfg=white ctermbg=black
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight CursorLineNr cterm=bold term=bold gui=bold
```

[config file](https://github.com/Monzim/Al-AsrVim)

Comment: It is not clear what you want to ask, but have you checked this guide: https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide?

Comment: I just want to convert this config in .lua

Answer (score 12):

### For Neovim

In your Lua configuration `init.lua`, you can use `vim.cmd` function to add highlight and create auto-command:

```lua
vim.cmd([[highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=0 guibg=lightgrey]])
vim.cmd([[highlight Normal ctermfg=white ctermbg=black]])
vim.cmd([[autocmd ColorScheme * highlight CursorLineNr cterm=bold term=bold gui=bold]])
```

---

### For Neovim >= 0.7

With this Neovim version, there is a new function in API to set highlight : [`nvim_set_hl`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_set_hl())

You could define your highlights with it in Lua:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "ColorColumn", { ctermbg=0, bg=LightGrey })
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "Normal", { ctermfg=White,  ctermbg=Black })
```

There is also [`nvim_create_autocmd`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_create_autocmd()) function in API to create auto-command in Lua:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("ColorScheme", 
  pattern="*",
  callback = function()
    vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "CursorLineNr", { cterm=bold, bold=true })   
  end,
)
```

Comment: How do I found out about this? It seems like everytime I use the help I never find what I want and resort to googling in the end. Is there some mapping from viml commands to lua bindings that have been implemented somewhere?

Comment: I guess you found out about this on StackOverfow.